# Seperate word and digits with regex

Tags: python, regex

I struggle with separating a given string `foobar123` between a word and a digit of unknown length with an underscore (Result: `foobar_123`). I've tried to use regex to find the match r1 (works). But after this, I have no idea, how to separate the corresponding match.

```
import re
x = "foobar123"
y = re.sub("[a-z]{1}\d{1}", "\1", x)
print(y) # Output: "fooba23"
```

I think it should be done with "\1" to access the previous match. So I've tried to replace the found match with itself, but this results in: fooba23. Shouldn't it be foobar123.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Sorry for the typo in the code above, it should be `[a-z]` not `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may

- captured the letter in one part, and the digits in the other one : `([a-z]+)([0-9]+)`
- replace with the group of letter, underscore, the digits : `\1_\2`

I've add the `re.I` for ignorecase

```
x = "Foobar123"
y = re.sub("([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", r"\1_\2", x, flags=re.I)
print(y)  # Foobar_123
```

Comment: You can simply replace the digits by an underscore followed by the digits, there's no need to capture the first part.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille We can capture letter, digits or both, here there 3 answers, each one is represented ;)

Comment: A common issue here, use `re.sub("([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", r"\1_\2", x, flags=re.I)`

Answer (score 6):

This could do the trick using a capture group of your digits?

```
import re
x = "foobar123"
y = re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'_\1', x)
print(y)
```

I escaped the backslashes using raw string. Something your forgot to do in yours =)

---

Funny alternative without a capturing group is to use [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) parameter of `re.sub`:

```
import re
x = "foobar123"
y = re.sub(r'(?=\d)', '_', x, 1)
print(y)
```

The pattern `(?=\d)` returns all positions followed by a digit but only the **first** (hence the 1 for `count`) gets replaced by an underscore.

Answer (score 2):

You could capture the last letter followed by a digit and append an underscore:

```
re.sub(r'([a-z])(?=\d)', r'\1_', x)
# 'foobar_123'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are matching 2 digits using `[0-9]{1}\d{1}` where the `{1}` is not needed and a char a-z before the digits is not taken into account.

You could do the replacement without a capturing group using the match only `\g<0>` followed by an underscore.

The pattern will match a char `[a-z]` and uses a positive lookahead `(?=\d)` to assert what is on the right is a digit.

```
import re
x = "foobar123"
y = re.sub("[a-z](?=\d)", "\g<0>_", x)
print(y) # Output: "foobar_123"
```